# Need Help Saving iTunes Preferences

Tags: itunes, hard-drive, imac, music

I have just bought a new iMac. I have iTunes installed on my new computer. All my iTunes preferences are set perfectly on my old iMac. I now want to move my external hard drives to my new iMac. This is where all my iTunes music stored. There is one slight problem... I can easily connect the hard drives to my new iMac... One thinks that just locating the names of the hard drives and taking your mouse and sliding the folders into iTunes will all arrange the albums and all the tracks with all the album names and artists and everything goes in it's right place... Wrong... Doesn't work that way. There is a way to copy your iTunes preferences so that when you attach your hard drives the first time your iTunes program knows exactly where to find everything and everything is in it's place. Someone out there must know. I used to do it all the time but now I have not done it in like 3 years... Someone help!

Answer (score 1):

Generally, even when the actual song files are located on another drive like you state yours is, the iTunes library is still in the ~/Music/iTunes folder on your main computer drive. You can usually get there in Finder by clicking on Music in the sidebar.

Copy the above folder (iTunes) from your old computer to your new one, making sure to put it in the same place. If you already opened iTunes on the new computer, there will probably already be an iTunes folder there, and it's okay to drag it to the trash.

Once you've copied the folder over and you plug in your external hard drive, open iTunes while holding the <kbd>Option</kbd> key on the keyboard. When you see a message that asks you to Choose iTunes Library, click Choose Library. Navigate to the Music folder and select iTunes. At this point it may take a few minutes for iTunes to load, depending on the size of your library, but everything should be in place.

Comment: Hi... I opened up my main hard drive as you suggested... then do I click on "Users" which open up to huge listing of files and scroll down to where it says "Music" click on that? There is a folder there called "iTunes"... Should I copy that onto a CD-R? And then once that's done take the disc and put in my DVD drive on my new computer and drag it into my music folder? I would probably have to delete the old "iTunes folder" already there? Does this sound right?

Comment: Yes, if the music is stored elsewhere, the iTunes folder should be small enough to fit on a CD-R. Everything else you said sounds correct.

Comment: I will try this next Friday when my new iMac arrives by mail. I have dumped huge music folders in people's iTunes and generally everything goes into the right place with all the albums and artists names but with my iTunes sometimes I rip albums into iTunes and I have to type in all the names of the tunes, the album name and the artists names. This makes it all organized and complete but when just dumping the entire file off a hard drive into the iTunes icon, because I have labeled so many myself... alot of titles don't transfer the names or artists. I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help tubedogg! I was able to transfer all my iTunes preferences to my new iMac with your help!